# How to extract header from webflux while consuming the event stream body?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, events, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm using WebClient to consume an infinite stream of events. This code seemed to work fine in tests:

```
webClient.get()
    .uri("/events")
    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(EventStreamBatch::class.java)
    .retry()
    .subscribe(
        { batches ->
            eventsConsumer.accept(batches.events.map { it.toInternalEvent() })
        },
        { error ->
            log.error(error)
        }
    )
```

Now I also want to extract a header from the response which I need to use while consuming the events. I tried to change `bodyToFlux()` to `toEntityFlux()` so I can get both the headers and the body. But I'm confused how to consume the body stream, while getting the header value at the same time.

```
...
    .retrieve()
    .toEntityFlux(EventStreamBatch::class.java)
    .subscribe { entity: ResponseEntity<Flux<EventStreamBatch>> ->

        val header = entity.headers["my-header"]?.firstOrNull()

        // How to consume the `entity.body` which is of type Flux<EventStreamBatch> ?
        // Create another `.subscribe()` here? Nested subscribe() seems incorrect, there must be a better way.
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's a good solution, but I ended up creating a flux of pair of body and the header, using `flatMapMany()`:

```
webClient.get()
    .uri("/events")
    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
    .retrieve()
    .toEntityFlux(EventStreamBatch::class.java)
    .flatMapMany { entity ->
        val header = entity.headers["my-header"]?.firstOrNull()
        return@flatMapMany when (entity.body) {
            null -> Flux.empty<Pair<EventStreamBatch, String>>()
            else -> entity.body!!.map { Pair(it, header) }
        }
    }
    .subscribe { (batch, header) ->
        // have both the body and the header here now
    }
```